# How to convert this apache mod rewrite to iis web.config

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-config, iis-express

I am using apache mod rewrite and i have a .htaccess rewrite statement. I would like to change over to use IIS server and would like to know if any one can give me advice on how to convert my existing .htaccess statement to iis web.config.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Expert Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Download url rewrite from Microsoft web platform installer. Url rewrite module can auto create the web.config when you specify the rules via their ui.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 7 you would use `<system.webServer><rewrite>` section.  There is an excellent article on translating .htaccess to web.config [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)

```
<rewrite>  
  <rules>
    <rule name="Your Rule" stopProcessing="true">      
       <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />      
         <conditions>        
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />        
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />        
         </conditions>      
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" />    
     </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: hi! i resolved it! you can download url_rewrite, it will auto create the web.config file using a simple ui rules